# (TSQLConnection) Why are the Left and Top properties only available in the .dfm file?

Tags: delphi, runtime, components

I'm just curious why you can drop a `TSQLConnection` on a form and it will add `Left` and `Top` properties to the `.dfm`:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  ...
  object SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
  end
end
```

But when you create it in code, the `Left` and `Top` properties are not members of the `TSQLConnection` class:

```
interface

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FSQLCon: TSQLConnection;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSQLCon := TSQLConnection.Create(Self);
  FSQLCon.Left := 280;
  FSQLCon.Top := 200;
end;
```

Compile:

```
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(30): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Left'
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(31): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Top'
```

Why are some properties only available for assignment in the `.dfm`?  Shouldn't you be able to assign all properties in code (`.pas`) that are set in the form (`.dfm`)?

FYI - Using Delphi XE2 (Update 3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The properties `Left` and `Top` for TComponent do not exist really. The are set for the designer in DefineProperties used by `ReadProperty` and `WriteProperties`.

Take a look at classes.pas.

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for pointing to `classes.pas` & `DefineProperties`.

Comment: +1. Just as a note: You'll find this common for non-visual controls (`TDataSource`, the ADO components, etc.). They have no runtime visibility, so they have no actual properties for positional information. The IDE adds pseudo positions (top and left) so it can be displayed in the proper location at designtime.